# Is there any bad code? ( Quick sorting time complexity on C )

Tags: c, sorting, merge

```
void QuickSort(int* x, int first, int last) {
    if (first >= last)
        ;
    else {
        int pivotindex = Partition(x, first, last);

        QuickSort(x, first, pivotindex - 1);
        QuickSort(x, pivotindex + 1, last); 
    }
}

int Partition(int* x, int first, int last) {
    int isbig = first + 1, issmall = last, tmp;

    while (1) {
        while (x[isbig++] < x[first] && isbig != last + 1);     // 

        while (x[issmall--] > x[first] && issmall != first);    // 

        if (isbig < issmall) {  //          tmp = x[issmall];
            x[issmall] = x[isbig];
            x[isbig] = tmp;
        }
        else {  //          tmp = x[first];
            x[first] = x[issmall]; 
            x[issmall] = tmp;

            break;  // 
        }
    }

    return issmall; //
}
```

I have a problem with this code. I code on myself.
It's working. But the matter is relatively slower than merge sort algorithm which I made.
I can't find what the problem is. 
(I knew as merge sort and quick sort time complexity is equal on non sorted data, but on 10,000 data  sort : [time comparison ignore korean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MjoT.png))

It's 10 times bigger than merge sort. I think it means code is bad.
But I can't find where it is.
Is there any bad part of code which makes time complexity BIGGER?

Comment: You seem to have commented out two critical lines ? (Or is the code just badly formatted ?)

Comment: Code uses `tmp`, but never sets it.

Comment: Guys thanks for responsing my question. I find the reason. Actully i was sort sorted arry. But i think it was non sorted arry.  That means the result time was the worst case time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick sort is `O(n^2)` in the worst case, which you're seeing here. This happens because you're using the first element of your array as the pivot and sorting sorted data, so the array gets divided into one element and n-1 elements.

For comparison, mergesort is always `O(n log n)`.

Instead of using `x[first]`, you can use `x[(first + last) / 2]` as the pivot.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot

Comment: Using the middle element won't give n^2 complexity on sorted data, which is a common case. It's possible to maliciously construct a case which will give n^2 complexity for any non-randomized choice of pivot

Comment: Well, I have removed my comment, maybe I should have not. But why is using the sorting function on a sorting data is a common case? I would say the opposite is true.

Comment: All good. I suppose you're right, it really depends on the use case